# socket.io Get data io.sockets.clients(); Not working anymore

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Before you can create objects with user properties on frontend and assign it to the socket.user property for each connection using a code like this ex below in the backend.

```
socket.on("new_visitor", user => {
    console.log("new_visitor", user);
    socket.user = user;
    emitVisitors();
});
```

then retrieve all these data through the sockets object eg.

```
 const getVisitors = () => {
     let clients = io.sockets.clients().connected;
     let sockets = Object.values(clients);
     let users = sockets.map(s => s.user);
     return users;
 };

//frontend
  componentWillMount() {
    axios.get('http://geoplugin.net/json.gp').then(res => {
      const {
        geoplugin_request,
        geoplugin_countryCode,
        geoplugin_city,
        geoplugin_region,
        geoplugin_countryName
      } = res.data;
      const visitor = {
        ip: geoplugin_request,
        countrycode: geoplugin_countryCode,
        city: geoplugin_city,
        state: geoplugin_region,
        country: geoplugin_countryName
      } 

      socket.emit("new_visitor", visitor);

      socket.on("visitors", visitors => {
        this.setState({
          visitors: visitors
        })          
      })
    });
  }
```

But now the io.sockets.clients is not working anymore and is not recognized as a function.Every API provided seem t return only the Id. For anyone who knows a workaround on this please let us know. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What version of socket.io and socket.io-client are you using ?

Comment: Bro, I'm currently using socket.io version 3.1.0.

Comment: Please include the piece of code where you do `socket.emit('new_visitor')`

Comment: Also updated above code with the same ff code from frontend. const visitor = { ip: geoplugin_request, countrycode: geoplugin_countryCode, city: geoplugin_city, state: geoplugin_region, country: geoplugin_countryName } socket.emit("new_visitor", visitor); socket.on("visitors", visitors => { this.setState({ visitors: visitors })

Comment: Thanks it is much clearer now ! I ll see if i can up with an example ... should be straight forward

Comment: completely updated my answer to give you some pointers for a solid solution

Comment: Thanks bro problem solved!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem : How to hold custom data for each socket (serverside)

For each socket that connects to your `socket-io` server you want to be able to  store some custom data in reference to said socket, so at a later point, other sockets can retrieve this information.

### Solution : Add a simple in-memory-store (serverside)

I strongly advise to not add anything or mutating the `socket` object. Instead use the socket `id` to maintain a simple in-memory store for all connected sockets.

> Please note: the following snippets are just pointers and are not meant to just be copy pasted. Instead, try to use them to understand your problem and adjust them to your needs.

## Server Side

```js
const store = {};

io.on('connection', function (socket) {

  // add socket to store, like this
  // note 'data' is null at this point, yet needs to be set
  store[socket.id] = {
    socket : socket, 
    data   : null
  }

  socket.on('SET_CLIENT_DATA', function (clientdata) {
    // here we receive data from frontend, and add it to the serverside reference
    store[socket.id].data = clientdata;
    
    // once a socket updates his custom client data
    // emit all custom data to all clients
    io.emit('ALL_CONNECTED_CLIENTS', Object.values(store).map(e => e.data));
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    // if socket disconnects, make sure to remove the reference in your store
    delete store[socket.id];
  });

});
```

## Client Side

```js
socket.emit("SET_CLIENT_DATA", clientdata);

socket.on("ALL_CONNECTED_CLIENTS", (allclients) => {
  
/* here the client receives all custom client data that we kept serverside for each connected client */ 
/* do some more code here */

});
```

Comment: Hi Bro thanks for the reply I've tried your suggestion but it returned only this Set from a promise object. The output is the ff.  Set(1) { '8yM31AM216OrDGN8AAAD' } .  I actually need the object which I passed in my frontend.

Comment: So you add some information to the socket object inside your client-side (frontend) code ? And then you need to access this information from your server-side code (backend) ? If that's the case then the problem is not "how to get connected clients" but something completely different.

Comment: Updated my answer with a suggestion - not tested though

Comment: To be specific I actually need the object which I passed in my frontend and saved in the property socket.user once connection was made for each user/socket. From the front end the server received it and mapped it to the socket.user property. I guess confused it to be the "connected clients" since I was passing user info on the object passed. Then showthem on a table in the front end showing all live users with their info. Normally using this helped me retrieve them. code:  let clients = io.sockets.clients().connected;   but this line of code is not working anymore.

Comment: I updated my answer, if this still does not help you need to be more specific on your question and add more details .

Comment: Hi Pascal thanks for the code above. I tried it but it returns the ff. errors (node:13556) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.values (<anonymous>) at getAllUserData

Comment: Glad i could help !